# Initial authentication check in ReactJS and Redux

Tags: authentication, reactjs, promise, redux, fetch-api

**Background**: I have an app that is showing a list of movies, but what I want to do is to show the list only for users who are authorized (by checking token stored on the local-storage).

so the flow I want to achieve is:

1. user enters the app main page
2. check if has token in local storage
3. if yes check if it is authorized
4. if authorized = show list, else don't show

so what I do right now is in my main (wrapper) component right after I create my store:

```
const store = configureStore();
var token = localStorage.get(authConstants.LOCAL_STORAGE_TOKEN_KEY);
if(token){
    store.dispatch(actions.checkInitialAuth(token));
}
```

checkInitialAuth actions is:

```
export function checkInitialAuth(token){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestLogin());
        return fetch(authConstants.API_USER_DETAILS, {headers: { 'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
            .then(function(response){
                if(!response.ok){
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(user){
                localStorage.set(authConstants.LOCAL_STORAGE_TOKEN_KEY, token);
                dispatch(receiveLogin(user)); // <==========
                dispatch(setTopMovies()); // <==========
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                // TODO: handle errors
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

so the question is, is it the right place to invoke the initial auth check right after the creating store and right before the element creation?

and now if I have to invoke more actions only if the user is authorized do I have to invoke them in the **`then`** inside the **`checkInitialAuth`** action? is it the right place to make all the action dispatch calls?

and last one, when the auth is wrong (I changed manually the token to be wrong on the local storage) the **`console.log(err)`** is logging as expected but I have also this annoying [401 error in the console](http://screencast.com/t/lgZllfjls5), can I somehow avoid it?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it the right place to invoke the initial auth check right after the creating store and right before the element creation?

Yes. Usually this is where all the initialization happens before store is passed to `Provider`.

> is it the right place to make all the action dispatch calls?

This depends a lot on your application logic. You component can check if a user is authenticated itself to display the correct content for 'topMovies'. But nothing stops you from dispatch more actions here.

> but I have also this annoying 401 error in the console, can I somehow avoid it?

It is the network request error. It is the response from the server your `fecth` is contacting. You can hide the error by change your Chrome Dev console filter if you really want to hide them (but why?).

Comment: thank you dude, about the 401, of course myself, personally, as a developer  want it to show as it makes debugging easier, but in production i prefer to hide it from the end user.

Comment: @DimaGimburg I don't think users would have their consoles open while loading the website. But if you really wish the error to go away, you can set up you server to send back all 200 status code,and using response data to indicate failure (not recommended at all though).